# Solovay model and an apparent contradiction

Tags: set-theory

Excuse me in advance if I am making a mistake.
  Consider a countable transitive model $\mathfrak{M}$ of ZFC and the model $\mathfrak{N}_1$ (Solovay model built above $\mathfrak{M}$). If, in $\mathfrak{M}\cap \mathbb{R}$ we build (using choice) a non-continuous solution (and hence non-monotone) $f$ to the Cauchy functional equation. Then $\mathfrak{N}_1$ is built by adding uncountably many random reals to $\mathfrak{M} \cap \mathbb{R}$. My question is: the extended solution to the Cauchy-functional equation is necessary monotone, and at the same time it extends the solution $f$ in $\mathfrak{M}$ which is non-monotone. A contradiction. Where the error lies?

Comment: $\mathfrak N_1$ is not built by simply adding random reals.

Comment: I suggest you first understand how $\mathfrak N_1$ is actually built. Otherwise, you won't really understand the problem. That $\mathfrak M\subset \mathfrak N_1$ is far from enough to make sense of "extending a solution in $\mathfrak M$ to a solution in $\mathfrak N_1$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the error is in talking about "the extended solution to the Cauchy functional equation." Where do you get that extended solution from? Specifically, how is it defined on the new reals of $\mathfrak N_1$?

Comment: Isn't $\mathfrak{M} \subset \mathfrak{N}_1$?

Comment: @user48900 Yes, but so what?

Comment: So a graph of a function in $\mathfrak{M}$ is a subset of a graph of a function in $\mathfrak{N}_1$, no?

Comment: @user48900 Yes, but there is no reason to think that such a function in $\mathfrak N_1$ would be a solution of the Cauchy functional equation.

Comment: Ok I see now, thank you.